# Access JobDatamap before execution

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net

Is there a way to retrieve the values of variables in a JobDataMap before the job executes?

I am basically trying to display the job's next chained job name in a view. The name is in the Datamap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the IJobDetail of a given job. It has a property called JobDataMap that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement custom `ITriggerListener` and/or `IJobListener` in which you can use the `TriggerFired` and `JobToBeExecuted` respectively in order to manipulate the job data map.

I use the `TriggerFired` for example for a "generic" database logging (all jobs triggered are input to DB without putting the code in the job itself).

These interfaces are mentioned in the tutorial

http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/lesson_7.html

couldn't find it in the 2.0 docs but the code in GitHub (read the XML docs):
https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/master/src/Quartz/ITriggerListener.cs
https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/master/src/Quartz/IJobListener.cs

Also found a short tutorial:
http://jvilalta.blogspot.co.il/2010/11/creating-quartznet-joblistener.html